# How to filter the contents of my tableview?

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a tableView which displays users email and data of birth, the problem is that the current users email and date of birth is also displayed in the list. How do I avoid that?

This is the code that I tried, the emails are taken from emailList[indexPath.row].

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "emailCell", for: indexPath)

    let snapshot = emailList[indexPath.row]

    if let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
        if let email = userDictionary["email"] as? String {
        if let DOB = userDictionary["DOB"] as? String {

        cell.textLabel?.text = email
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = DOB

          }
      }
  }
```

I want to see a list of the users emails and date of birth in the tableView but without the current users info.

Comment: can you put a breakpoint to check what are these values ?  

cell.textLabel?.text = email
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = DOB

Comment: what do you mean by breakpoints?

Comment: filter the dataSource, not the table view.

Comment: @Gereon how do you filter the dataSource?

Comment: You must have code that assigns stuff to `emailList`. Remove the user's own entry right there and then using e.g. `.filter` on the array.

Comment: something like this //  let CurrentUserEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
    var filteredEmails : [DataSnapshot] {
        return emailRequests.filter {
            (($0.value as? [String:AnyObject])?["email"] as? String) != CurrentUserEmail
            
        }
    }

Comment: This is horrible to read in a comment, but looks like it's going the right direction.

Comment: sorry. i tried that code but im getting an error in my viewDidLoad Part "self.filteredEmails.append(snapshot)" Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'filteredEmails' is a get-only property

Comment: what do you mean with `without the current users info`? Can you explain a bit better what you want to filter? maybe provide a example of the `emailList` before and after filtering. @Nick

Comment: Hi @zero3nna i have a tableView that displays a list of users emails and date of birth, but when you look at the list, you will still see the current users email and DOB. I dont want to see the current users infos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you get your current user data as well as the emailList you can filter emailList using something like this

```
func downloadData(_ completionHandler: (AnyObject?) -> ()){
 let data:AnyObject? = //perform the logic to download data
 completionHandler(data)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    downloadData(){ data in
      //Do stuff with data - parse it etc.
       guard let emailList = emailList as? [[String:String]] // cast to the type you need
       else { 
         return  // Do some error handling
       } 
       let filteredData = emailList.filter { (dict: [String:String]) -> Bool in
         if dict["email"] == currentEmail && dict["user"] == currentUsername {
           return false
         }
         return true
       }
      self.tableView.delegate = self
      self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

Comment: where will i put this? in viewDidLoad?

Comment: You have to use this code after you get all the necessary data (emailList and current user data) the best option would be to use the completion handler. Completion handler would allow you to call this piece of code after the data will be download.

Comment: sorry im not yet familiar with completion handlers

Comment: I added completion handler example to my answer. Of course my answer is very generic and you have to adjust it to fit in your project